# Append CSVs without column names

Tags: python, csv, pandas, append

I have a list of CSVs , but they don't have column names. With my code in Python 2.7 it appends but the first row in each CSV is recognized as the column names. How can I append the CSVs without column names. For example:

```
1 2 3
a b 3

2 4 1
a e r

Append:
1 2 3
a b 3
2 4 1
a e r
```

The code is the following:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

targetdir = r'E:/tals/ICF/Base Admision San Marcos 2015-1'

filelist = os.listdir(targetdir) 

big_df=pd.DataFrame()

for filename in filelist:
    big_df = big_df.append(pd.read_csv(os.path.join(targetdir, filename)),ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set [`header=None`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-read-csv-table):

```
big_df.append(pd.read_csv(file, header=None), ignore_index=True)
```